# How to correctly make a nested for loop using a defined function to produce an array of values

Tags: python-3.x, function, jupyter-notebook, sum, jupyter

I have defined my function (the partition function partfunc_E, a function of ionisation energy chiI and a temperature T) and have to create a nested for loop to first, loop over the values of ionisation energies (chiI, a vector) and an inner loop to evaluate the sum over all energy states for the ion (here I am using 5). The output should be a vector of partition function values associated with each ionisation energy in the chiI array.

(From our instructions): For an energy of 10,000K, using the ionisation energies of calcium and a temperature of 10,000K should give something like:

```
[ 1.45605581  1.45648718  1.45648849  1.45648849  1.45648849]
```

Note: g=1 for all states.

I don't know what I have done wrong but I am not getting what they expect at all, I am getting an array of length 100 and all the values in the array are the same. The following code is my attempt.

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from astropy import units as u
from astropy import constants as const
%matplotlib inline

k = const.k_B.to('eV*K**-1')
#print(k)

def partfunc_E(chiI,T):
    return g*np.exp(-(chiI/(k*T)))

chiI = [6.1131554, 11.871719, 50.91316, 67.2732, 84.34]*u.eV
T=(10000)*u.K
g= 1

partition_Ca = []

for i in chiI:
    for j in range(0,10,1):
        function = partfunc_E(chiI,T)
        partition_Ca.append(sum(partfunc_E(chiI,T)))
```

Comment: `alist * n` replicates the list `n` times.  It is not numeric multiplication.  Look at `chiI`.  In the nested loop, why aren't you using the `i` and `j` variables?  Looks like you need to step back from `astropy`, and practice some more with simple Python code - lists and for loops.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying n is here in my code? If you mean g, then g has to equal 1 according to our instructions. Also, I was using i and j to call those elements of each array in, not variables? I have to use astropy for the units here and have used simple python code for loops, that's why I have tried what I have tried, I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong. I don't see how your comment answers that.

Comment: I also has the same problem when I created the array of energies named "energies" and in the loop I used "for chiI in energies' rather than 'for i in chiI' etc and it still did not work. That's why I tried using i and j instead.

Comment: Maybe the problem isn't with the `chiI` expression (but still check that).  But in your loop you append the same value to `partition_Ca` each time.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing something like this:

```
In [336]: x = np.arange(3) 
     ...: alist = [] 
     ...: for i in x: 
     ...:     for j in range(2): 
     ...:         alist.append(np.exp(x).sum()) 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [337]: alist                                                                                
Out[337]: 
[11.107337927389695,
 11.107337927389695,
 11.107337927389695,
 11.107337927389695,
 11.107337927389695,
 11.107337927389695]
```

this puts the same value into `alist` each time.  The looping does nothing new:

```
In [338]: np.exp(x).sum()                                                                      
Out[338]: 11.107337927389695
```

You could instead use `i`, the iteration variable in the loop:

```
In [339]: x = np.arange(3) 
     ...: alist = [] 
     ...: for i in x: 
     ...:     alist.append(np.exp(i)) 
     ...:                                                                                      
In [340]: alist                                                                                
Out[340]: [1.0, 2.718281828459045, 7.38905609893065]
```

But since `np.exp` works with an array, there's no need to iterate.

```
In [341]: np.exp(x)                                                                            
Out[341]: array([1.        , 2.71828183, 7.3890561 ])
```

As I demonstrate, you need to experiment with some basic Python loops, and check the results in detail.  Don't write a big script and then scratch your head when the results aren't right.  Test pieces, and make sure you understand each step.

Comment: I am now using the following format (this comment wont let me add this like a block of properly formatted code for some reason):


```partition_Ca = [] 
function = []

for chiI in ionisation_E:
    for i in energy_lev:
        function = partfunc_E(chiI,T)
        print(function)```

This is returning me 25 total values, 5 lots of 5 of the same answers. How can I sum each group of 5 same answers within this array?